# Finding a numbers with the largest/smallest number of bits set

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Given a range of integers, how do I find the numbers within the range with the largest and the lowest number of bits set?

For example, given the range `[32, 65]`, 63 has the largest number of bits set (i.e. six, because the binary representation is `111111`) and 32 and 64 have the lowest (i.e. one, because the binary representation are `100000` and `1000000`).

Has to work fast for very large numbers/ranges (2^50).

Comment: So are you asking, for any given length `n`, what are the upper and lower bounds of bit strings of that length? I'm confused what that range `[33, 65]`is for

Comment: You mean 64, because 32 isn't in that range. I'd guess you just need to find the largest power of 2 in the range, and then it's that number for the min and that number -1 for the max. If no powers of two then I'd guess binary search between the power of two above and the power of two below to find a value in the range, which will have been expressed with one bit per search iteration and so the fewest: ditto that's the max, and that number -1 = the min. But I haven't thought about this too carefully.

Comment: No need to do binary search; an XOR between the lower and upper bounds of the range will tell you the highest bit where they are different, and that allows you to work out the answer in constant time.

Comment: How is `32` in the range of `[33, 65]` ?

Comment: Why is anybody voting that the question needs more focus? Except for the easily correctable error about 32, the problem is clear, well-defined, and properly stated.

Comment: [Counting Bits - Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive)? (see all methods)

Comment: If you are on a modern CPU and do not care about portability, you should indeed use `__builtin__popcount()` or some intrinsic like `_mm_popcnt_u64()` or `_mm_popcnt_u32()`. If you care about portability, see the link in @DavidC.Rankin 's comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try to find the highest power of 2 that is within the range. This can be done by taking the upper bound and ANDing it with itself minus one in a loop, like:

```
temp = upper_bound;
while( (temp & (temp-1)) != 0) {
    temp = temp & (temp-1);
}

if(temp < lower_bound) {
    // No power of 2 found within range
}
```

If no power of 2 within the range is found by the previous step; you would've found a power of 2 that is not in range. Clear the corresponding bit in the upper and lower bounds and recurse; like:

```
void find_bits(unsigned int lower_bound, unsigned int upper_bound, unsigned int extra_bits) {
    unsigned int temp = upper_bound;
    while( (temp & (temp-1)) != 0) {
        temp = temp & (temp-1);
    }

    if(temp < lower_bound) {
        find_bits(lower_bound ^ temp, upper_bound ^ temp, extra_bits + 1);
        return;
    }
```

If zero is within the range, then the smallest number of set bits is zero (from the number zero). Otherwise, the smallest number of set bits is one (from any power of 2 within range, including the highest power of 2 you found). Don't forget to account for any extra bits that were previously cleared:

```
    if(lower_bound == 0) {
        least_set_bits = 0 + extra_bits;
    } else {
        least_set_bits = 1 + extra_bits;
    }
```

If the highest power of 2 within range minus 1 is also within the range, then the largest number of set bits will be however many bits is in highest power of 2 within range minus 1. Otherwise, the upper bound must have been the same as the lower bound and therefore the largest number of set bits is equal to the smallest number of set bits:

```
    if(temp - 1 < lower_bound) {
        most_set_bits = least_set_bits;
    } else {
        temp--;
        most_set_bits = 0;
        while(temp > 0) {
            temp >>= 1;
            most_set_bits++;
        }
        most_set_bits += extra_bits;
    }
```

All of the above combined (and untested and probably buggy; and definitely not able to handle some corner cases - e.g. if the range is [0, 0]):

```
void find_bits(unsigned int lower_bound, unsigned int upper_bound, unsigned int extra_bits) {
    unsigned int temp = upper_bound;
    unsigned int least_set_bits;
    unsigned int most_set_bits;

    while( (temp & (temp-1)) != 0) {
        temp = temp & (temp-1);
    }

    if(temp < lower_bound) {
        find_bits(lower_bound ^ temp, upper_bound ^ temp, extra_bits + 1);
        return;
    }

    if(lower_bound == 0) {
        least_set_bits = 0 + extra_bits;
    } else {
        least_set_bits = 1 + extra_bits;
    }

    if(temp - 1 < lower_bound) {
        most_set_bits = least_set_bits;
    } else {
        temp--;
        most_set_bits = 0;
        while(temp > 0) {
            temp >>= 1;
            most_set_bits++;
        }
        most_set_bits += extra_bits;
    }

    printf("Least set bits is %u, most set bits is %u.\n", least_set_bits, most_set_bits);
}
```

Comment: I do not think this is correct. If you call function `find_bits` like so `find_bits(16, 24, 0);` then the output is `Least set bits is 1, most set bits is 1.` This is incorrect, for 22 four bits are set (`010110`). Looking for a bug...

Comment: @az5112: For `find_bits(16, 24, 0)` it should decide that the highest power of 2 is 16 and do `find_bits(0, 8, 1)`. For `find_bits(0, 8, 1)` it should decide that the highest power of 2 is 8, then to determine `most_set_bits` it should count the number of set bits in 7 to get 3, then add the extra bit to get 4. This would be the correct answer (10111b = 23, which has 4 set bits).

Comment: @az5112: Ah - I think you're right. The `if(temp < lower_bound) {` should probably be `if(temp <= lower_bound) {`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the range [`lower`, `upper`] with `unsigned` `lower` and `upper`, let `diff = lower ^ upper` be the bits that are different in `lower` and `upper`.

If `diff` is zero, the `lower` and `upper` are identical, so the least number of bits and the greatest number of bits set in the range is the number of bits set in `lower`.

Otherwise, let `n` be the number of the greatest bit set in `diff`, starting counting from 0 for the least significant bit. Let `mask = (2u << n) - 1` be a mask for the bits up to and including bit `n`. (Note `2u` is correct.) Partition `lower` and `upper` into shared high bits and separate low bits:

```
shared = lower & ~mask;
lower &= mask;
upper &= mask;
```

Count the bits set in `shared`. They are necessarily set in any value in the original [`lower`, `upper`]. Below, we solve for the new `lower` and `upper`. Then the solution for the original values is obtained by adding the number of bits set in `shared`.

If `lower` is zero, the least number of bits set is zero, since 0 is in [`lower`, `upper`], Otherwise, it is one, since `1u << n` is in [`lower`, `upper`].

If `upper` equals `mask`, the greatest number of bits set is `n+1`, the number of bits set in `mask`. Otherwise, it is `n`, since `(1u << n) - 1` is in [`lower`, `upper`].